# Who woke up the astronauts in Oblivion?

Tags: plot-explanation, oblivion

Near the end of Oblivion when Jack is having flashbacks to being an astronaut. He remembers piloting the spacecraft towards the alien ship. My understanding was that Jack and Victoria were both asleep in the pods, and that mission control awoke them when intercepting the unknown artifact (the alien ship).

While on route to intercept the artifact Jack is in constant contact with mission control. The woman in the video screen is the same as the woman seen earlier in the film. So it seems that Jack was following orders made by the alien, and not actually mission control.

My question is who woke up Jack and Victoria? Were they awoken by the alien and tricked into thinking they were communicating with mission control. Or, was the woman on the screen a real person back in mission control and not the alien?

Comment: What makes you say they were asleep?

Comment: That's a good question as well. I thought it was stated after reviewing the flight recorder that 2 of the crew were awoken from sleep by mission control on their way to Titan. The mission was redirected to intercept the alien ship. This is why Jack's wife didn't know about the aliens, cause she was expecting to awake at Titan.

Comment: 1) Julia knew about the TET -- she explains this at the ruins of Empire State building that their mission was reconfigured to analyse the TET before the launch.

Comment: 2) The video feed from NASA mission control was likely real and not intercepted, but the engine burst data to approach TET and keep stable distance was likely intercepted and changed so that Odyssey approaches it without stopping.

Comment: I thought that mission control was the real one from NASA. Later *TET* just reused existing elements and motives (like the real mission control, or the photo made by *Victoria*) in its staging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They were woken by Sally from mission control she was the woman on the screen and is a real person back in mission control.

The  woman that we see earlier in the film is a copy of the real Sally from mission control.  The TET mimics the interaction between Sally and Jack/Victoria.

The only thing I can use to prove this is the quality of video feed. When the TET is using Sally the video quality is poor and it also jumps a bit, while during the scenes from inside the Odyssey it was much better. If the TET didn't edit and reuse an old video you would expect it to be better quality given its advanced technology.

Comment: Good answer. I just found that stance of the woman kind of strange. She stands perfectly straight and speaks very much like the first videos. Has an inhuman feel to. I'd hate to watch the movie again. :)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini *"She stands perfectly straight and speaks very much like the first videos."* - No, it's rather that the first videos very much speak like her. Maybe you found the real *Sally* so strange because you met *TET*'s version first?

Comment: My feeling was this: When the computer mimics Sally, there was a hardness and coldness in her tone. She says things like "Are you functioning at optimum level?" She is very machine like and too the point. But the real Sally I found to be warm and friendly. I think the actress did a good job- she portrayed both versions quite well, using only subtle changes

Answer (score 7):

The question in the title appears to have been unanswered in the accepted answer.

> My question is who woke up Jack and Victoria? Were they awoken by the alien and tricked into thinking they were communicating with mission control. Or, was the woman on the screen a real person back in mission control and not the alien?

They were woken either automatically by the ship itself or by NASA remotely. It's also possible that one member of the crew was always awake on a shift basis. Currently, a journey to Saturn can take anywhere between three and seven years hence the need for the "delta sleep" pods.

Jack Harper is woken up on schedule. We know this as he is aware that the Superbowl would have been held the previous night and NASA's Sally threatens to spoil the game for him by telling him who won. Considering that the Tet was the primary mission, why the other members of the crew were not woken up defeats me. The nature of the conversation makes it unlikely that the Tet was already impersonating Sally.

Comment: a bit late, but fair point about the question in the title.  I have updated it accordingly :-)